# Fluent NHibernate Mapping One-To-Many in one Table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've the following Database Table:

```
CREATE TABLE RestrictedSystemUsages
(
    WorkflowArtifactIdentifier varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    RestrictedSystemUsageId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
);
```

I want to map the following Class into it:

```
public class RestrictedSystemUsages
{
    public virtual string WorkflowArtifactIdentifier { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Guid> RestrictedSystemUsageIds { get; set; }
}
```

But I've no clue how the fluent mapping is to be done.

I've tried to apply the following mapping but it won't work at all:

```
        Id(x => x.WorkflowArtifactIdentifier).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

        HasMany(x => x.RestrictedSystemUsageIds)
            .Table("RestrictedSystemUsageForWorkflow")
            .Element("RestrictedSystemUsageId")
            .AsBag();
```

Can anybody point me to the correct mapping for the Guid-List please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Mapping was all I need:

```
Id(x => x.WorkflowArtifactIdentifier).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

HasMany(x => x.RestrictedSystemUsageIds)
    .Element("RestrictedSystemUsageId")
    .KeyColumn("WorkflowArtifactIdentifier")
    .Table("RestrictedSystemUsageForWorkflow")
    .AsSet();
```

With one flaw, it will add an additional row with an empty RestrictedSystemUsageId column.